# How to select record from XML using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML document.

```
<checksum>
    <kbbest>
        <delimiter value="length" offset="0">2</delimiter>
        <record name="header">
            <identificators>
                <identificator value="char('2')" offset="0">HO</identificator>
                <identificator value="char('2')" offset="0">HE</identificator>
            </identificators>
            <fields>
                <!-- some fields -->
            </fields>
        </record>
        <record name="footer">
            <identificators>
                <identificator value="char('2')" offset="0">TO</identificator>
                <identificator value="char('2')" offset="0">TF</identificator>
            </identificators>
            <fields>
                <!-- some fields -->
            </fields>
            </record>
    </kbbest>
</checksum>
```

I want to select all information stored in record according to identificator.
My Script:

```
string recordType = "HE"
IEnumerable<XElement> rec = null;
rec = from xr in doc.Element(fileType).Elements("record")
      where (string)xr.Element("identificators").Element("identificator") == recordType
      select xr;
```

Error: This select can find only records which has identificator HO or TO.

If I tried to write it as an list

```
string recordType = "HE"
IEnumerable<XElement> rec = null;
rec = from xr in doc.Element(fileType).Elements("record")
      where xr.Element("identificators").Elements("identificator").Cast<String>().Contains(recordType)
      select xr;
```

Error: Can't cast XElement to String

Comment: You need to select the `XElement.Value`.  Also I believe you should look into using `Descendants` to get at the elements of type "record".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

```
string recordType = "HE"
IEnumerable<XElement> rec = null;
rec = from xr in doc.Element(fileType).Descendants ("record")
      where xr.Element("identificators")
              .Elements("identificator")
              .Any(x => x.Value == recordType)
      select xr;
```

you need to use `Descendants` to get at any elements that are more than one level deep.  Then you have to compare the `Value` of the `XElement` to the string value.